# How is EXP gained from Power-Up Fusion calculated?

Tags: puzzle-and-dragons

With a Vampire Lord as Base Monster, a level 3 Baddie (purple glob, 1 star, cost: 1) would gain him 225 EXP. A level 3 Purple Carbuncle (1 star, cost: 2) would gain him 338 EXP. At the same time, the EXP gain is the sum of them both. Is it that the level and Cost of the Monster combine to determine how EXP is gained from using them as Material in fusion?

Comment: You have a lot of Puzzle and Dragons questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wiki has a very detailed accounting of exp gains from Power-Up Fusion [here](http://pad.wikia.com/wiki/Game_Mechanics) (under Fusion Screen)

A summary is that the EXP value is based on the fused monster's species and level. Every monster has a different exp-per-level value. You can also multiply the exp received by 1.5x by feeding monsters of the same element. Further, the result of 'Good', 'Great' and 'Super' increase the exp bonus by 100%, 150% and 200% respectively.